Is it fine to use #6 x 1 5/8" screws when hanging 1/2" drywall?
It's my understanding 1 1/4" is the best for 1/2" drywall but I have a huge box of these 1 5/8" screws lying around. Someone mentioned 1 1/4" is how far back electricians have to run wires through studs, but not sure how accurate that is. Makes sense to me though. (Texas)
Any other codes I should look up before hanging drywall the first time?

You were informed correctly. The National Electrical Code requires wiring that is not at least 1 1/4" back from the face of the stud to be protected by a metal plate as Jack points out in his answer. This is just one reason the drywallers do not use 2" or longer screws. If you already have the longer screws and there is no wiring or plumbing to be concerned with such as a ceiling then by all means use them. The difference in length is probably not as important as the threads. Make sure you have coarse threads for wood and the finer threads for metal studs.

If hanging drywall, you should know exactly if any wires/pipes are there(outside walls with insulation a bit harder).  Mark positions of the nasty stuff and use smaller nails near them.

8” spacing on the edge; 16” spacing in the field is typical code for walls. (6/12 for ceilings.) Professionals in my orbit just do 6/12 on the walls to guarantee a screw inspection pass.

The info is correct about the 1 1/4" back from the face of the studs. Any closer there needs to be a protective metal plate over that area of the stud where the wire passes through so fasteners will not go through the wire or plumbing pipe too for that matter.
Using 1 5/8" screws in 1/2" sheetrock will only take longer the run all the screws.
